# universal Windows apps using Mvvm, can't use resource resw file

Tags: c#, wpf, image, mvvm, resources

Im  developing a universal windows app using Mvvm-Pattern containing an

App for **Windows** and for **Windows Phone**.

Beside these two projects I've got a **Shared-Project** where I have my

**ViewModel** and **Model**

At the moment everything is ok works fine. Logic and View ist absolutly seperated.

But now: I want to load around 50 to 200 images into my ViewModel or View, which are ordered in a specific way.

How should I load those pictures into my Project or into my ViewModel?

put it into a resource.resw-File?  oder just into the folder-Structures  or download it and put it then into the local storage?

I have at the moment no clue! And I also don't know how to iterate through them.

I tried to itereate through my folder-structure in my shared-project, but many functions are not implemented which I could use whene I had a WPF-Desktop-Application.

Answer (score 0):

Are the images constant or something that'd be changed throughout the application run? Are they local or webbased?

If they're constant, you could add them to Assets in an 'Images' folder (right click on Assets/Images > Add> Existing Item). Then you can source them by "/Assets/Images/img1.png"

As for accessing your local folder there are 2 approaches:

1. Local Folder- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder

There are extension methods for localdirectory class that will allow you to get a list of files (and you get local directory (say '/Assets/Images') through using localfolder methods)

2. Using the old fashioned path strings, with the caveat that local folder is "ms-appx:///" (notice the 3 "/"). So accessing you'd do something like "ms-appx:///Assets/Images/Img.png"

More info here- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965322.aspx (they're